# best practice to update a field in list of dictionary of list and dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Assuming the input is a list of dictionary.
I need to update a specific field with new values.
There are repeated keys, values in the input so cannot distinguish the field need to be picked by its name.
Here is an example:

```
test = [
{
    "key": "prog",
    "value": {
        "instance[]": [
            {
                "key": "name",
                "value": {
                    "string": "NAME"
                },
                "verif": 22222222
            },
            {
                "key": "user",
                "value": {
                    "string": "AAAAA"
                },
                "verif": 22222222
            }
        ]
    },
    "verif": 22222222
},
{
    "key": "sytem_platform",
    "value": {
        "bool": "false"
    },
    "verif": 22222222
},
{
    "key": "system_beh",
    "value": {
        "bool": "true"
    },
    "verif": 22222222
},
{
    "key": "check_beh",
    "value": {
        "bool": "true"
    },
    "verif": 22222222
},
{
    "key": "order",
    "value": {
        "instance[]": [
            {
                "key": "order_det",
                "value": {
                    "instance[]": [
                        {
                            "key": "requires",
                            "value": {
                                "string[]": []
                            },
                            "verif": 22222222
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "status",
                            "value": {
                                "string[]": []
                            },
                            "verif": 22222222
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "system_status",
                            "value": {
                                "string[]": [
                                    "sys1.out",
                                    "sys1.checking"
                                ]
                            },
                            "verif": 22222222
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "weather_status",
                            "value": {
                                "instance[]": [
                                    {
                                        "key": "humdiity",
                                        "value": {
                                            "double": 5.0
                                        },
                                        "verif": 22222222
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key": "temp",
                                        "value": {
                                            "double": 70.0
                                        },
                                        "verif": 22222222
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "verif": 22222222
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "environment",
                            "value": {
                                "string[]": []
                            },
                            "verif": 22222222
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "verif": 22222222
            }
        ]
    },
    "verif": 22222222
}
```

]

I am trying to update the following section of it like adding "aaaa" and "bbb"

```
        "instance[]": [
            {
                "key": "requires",
                "value": {
                    "string[]": ["aaaa", "bbb"]
                },
```

I was wondering if there is any built-in library in python that i can use for this goal?

i can filter it out and store it in a list like below, but i am not sure how i can update it.

```
newl = [d for d in test if d["key"] == "order" ]
print(newl)
#which prints
[{'key': 'order', 'value': {'instance[]': [{'key': 'order_det', 'value': {'instance[]': [{'key': 'requires', 'value': {'string[]': []}, 'verif': 22222222}, {'key': 'status', 'value': {'string[]': []}, 'verif': 22222222}, {'key': 'system_status', 'value': {'string[]': ['sys1.out', 'sys1.checking']}, 'verif': 22222222}, {'key': 'weather_status', 'value': {'instance[]': [{'key': 'humdiity', 'value': {'double': 5.0}, 'verif': 22222222}, {'key': 'temp', 'value': {'double': 70.0}, 'verif': 22222222}]}, 'verif': 22222222}, {'key': 'environment', 'value': {'string[]': []}, 'verif': 22222222}]}, 'verif': 22222222}]}, 'verif': 22222222}]
```

Comment: I suggest a wrapper class instead of ```dict```, so you can change the internals afterwards. The square bracket operations (```x[key]``` and ```x[key]=a```) can be implemented using ```__getitem__``` and ```__setitem__```. Example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__getitem__-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion to find the dict with the specified key.

```py
def get(o, k):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        for x in o:
            if res := get(x, k):
                return res
    elif o['key'] == k:
        return o
    elif nxt := o.get('value', {}).get('instance[]'):
        return get(nxt, k)
o = get(test, 'requires')
if o:
    o['value']['string[]'] += "aaaa", "bbb"
print(test) # test now changed
```